# React not rendering AJAX data

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, html-table

I am attempting to load data into a table using react, and I got to the point where the data does exist when attempting to render the fragment, however, it doesn't seem to actually update the dom and render (I tested and know the data DOES in fact exist when it runs the fragment in the {} block under tbody. Any help would be awesome, thank you.

```
import React from 'react';

class InvoicePickTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {invoices:[]};
    }

    getInvoiceData(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log("hi");
            resolve([{number: "1"},{number: "2"},{number: "3"}]);
        })

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const self = this;
        self.getInvoiceData()
        .then((response) => {
            self.setState({invoices: response});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Invoice #</th>
                        <th>Task Price</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Task Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {

                    this.state.invoices.forEach(function (invoice) {
                        console.log("in");
                        console.log(invoice);
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{invoice.number}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}

export default InvoicePickTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
this.state.invoices.map(invoice => <tr><td>{invoice.number}</td></tr>)
```

in your render function. `Array.forEach` does not actually return an array

Comment: Although you answered your own question, it is important for future visitors to realize why. You are not imperatively telling React HOW to render -- you are returning a tree of WHAT React will render. That is why forEach -- which doesn't return anything -- doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, you need to use MAP not FOR EACH, hope this helps someone!

```
import React from 'react';

class InvoicePickTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {invoices:[]};
    }

    getInvoiceData(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log("hi");
            resolve([{number: "1"},{number: "2"},{number: "3"}]);
        })

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const self = this;
        self.getInvoiceData()
        .then((response) => {
            self.setState({invoices: response});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Invoice #</th>
                        <th>Task Price</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Task Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {

                    this.state.invoices**.map**(function (invoice) {
                        console.log("in");
                        console.log(invoice);
                        return (
                            <tr **key = {invoice.number}**>
                                <td>{invoice.number}</td>
                                <td>1231</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>A Task</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}

export default InvoicePickTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#hook-up-the-data-model) is a good example of rendering the data with ajax and `map` function.